# How to set title for a single page inside document

Tags: graphics, captions, header-footer

I would like to ask for an advise about how to set title of the single page inside the document (not the title page, but regular page in document). I'd like to have picture on whole page with caption in title of the page.

For whole document I use the `article` class.

Comment: Are you asking about how to create a *title page* (first page of the document with the title on it)? Or how to create a page in the middle of the document with its own "title" to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could solve that with the fancyhdr package. It's not "the" nice and clean solution, but possible:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

[...]
\pagebreak
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{} % left header text
\chead{} % center header text
\rhead{} % right header text
\lfoot{} % left footer text
\cfoot{} % center footer text
\rfoot{} % right footer text
[your image here]
\pagebreak
[...]
```

Setting all `\[lcr](head|foot) {}` clears the header. You could just set the part you want to change anyway. All commands are in the snipet above.

Comment: Why you not just say `\thispagestyle{empty}`? Also how would you set the required title text?

Comment: @Martin I think @Georg means to put the image's title into the header of the page. I saw that in at least one book with full-page images and the tags let me also assume that. The title text would then be set with `\chead{Image Title}` if I'd do that.